# How to change an IEnumerable collection so that it can be bound to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ienumerable

I am developing an WPF application. It is having a `DataGrid` in it. I have assigned the `ItemSource` of my datagrid to an `IEnumerable` collection.
I have a `Treeview` in my window. When I click the element in the treeview it has to load the datagrid

```
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
       this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;

       this.dataGrid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = objref.FinalValue;
       // Where Objref.FinalValue is an IEnumerable collection. 
       grid_data = objref.FinalValue;
}
```

But the problem is everytime the `selection` is changed, the values in the `datagrid` is not overwrittenen but it is appended. I flushed the datagrid with `dataGrid1.Columns.Clear()` and `dataGrid.ItemSource = null;` Later I found out that the `objref.FinalValue` is appended. So even though I flushed the datagrid it displays the entire value..

So in the class which is having `objref` as instance I have used

```
   private IEnumerable Result;

   public IEnumerable FinalValue
   {
       get { return Result; }
       set { Result = value; }
   }
   // Update Result with values so that it can be assigned to datagrid.
```

I need to overwrite not append. But the `FinalValue` has been appended every time. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you update the `ItemsSource` after the grid is rendered you have to call `dataGrid1.Items.Refresh()` to update it. After calling `Refresh()` the datagrid rows will reflect the new collection that is bound to it.

Comment: @Desperatar : Thank u for ur interest. Real problem is not associated with updating the datagrid. Even i have tried that Refresh(); . My IEnumerable collection is appended everytime. so eventhough i refresh my datagrid will show appended version only.

Comment: Then you need to pull your focus away from the datagrid and look at where you are setting and modifying the value of FinalValue as these are two unrelated things. You can try posting some more code, but the best advice I can give is to set lots of break points and carefully watch the FinalValue variable. This way you can see the moment it changes and this will be a big clue as to what the real issue is.